# search what is inside an array and return what is next to it

Tags: php, arrays

```
H2O -> H2 + O2
```

I converted the previous string into two arrays :

```
Array ( [0] => H2 [1] => O2 ) 
Array ( [0] => H2O )
```

I also created another array from the string which gets all the elements in the reaction

```
Array ( [0] => H [1] => O )
```

what I am trying to do is get the number beside the element and make an array from it. In this case, I am trying to achieve something like this :

array to find the number beside the H in the equation

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 0 ) 
Array ( [0] => 2 )
```

array to find the number beside the O in the equation

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 2 ) 
Array ( [0] => 1 )
```

which is basically demonstrated in this table :

```
    H2      +      O2    ->       H2O
H:   2             0               2
O:   0             2               1
```

How can I achieve such a thing. I am trying to create a chemical balancer and I am stuck in this step.

more advanced question.. when searching for an element what if there you have an element like this : Ba(NO3)2 how can you account for 2 Nitrogens and 6 oxygens when creating the array.

Comment: `H2O -> H2 + O2` - I'm no chemist, but are you sure that's H2O and not H2O + one remaing O ?

Comment: @AxelAmthor it is actually `2(H2O) -> 2H2 + O2`. I am trying to create an equation balancer which I found would be great to improve my php array skills. so, the big picture I am trying to go from `H2O -> H2 + O2` to `2(H2O) -> 2H2 + O2`

Comment: But the instead for a bunch of arrays I would go for an aproach with a multi-dimensional array. Elements(1) => Numbers(2). These are the lines of your last table. You might then directly calculate the last column in your table by iterating and adding.

Comment: Can you explain why H in H2O get 2, and O in H2O get 1? Oh never mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    function chemistry($arr)
    {
        $result = array();
        array_walk($arr, function($value) use (&$result)
        {
            preg_match_all("#([A-Z][a-z]*)(\d*)#", $value, $match);

            $formula = array_combine($match[1],
                array_map(function($val)
                {
                    if(intval($val) == 0)
                        return "1"; 
                    else
                        return $val;
                }, $match[2]));
            if(count($formula) == 1)
            {
                $result[$match[1][0]] = $formula[$match[1][0]];
            }
            else
                $result = $formula;
        });
        return $result;
    }
    $left = array("H2", "O2");
    $right = array("H2O");
    print_r(chemistry($right));
    print_r(chemistry($left));
```

**Output**:

```
Array             # for H2O
(
    [H] => 2
    [O] => 1
)
Array             # for H2, O2
(
    [H] => 2
    [O] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am interested to solve your problem, however I try to solve it using OOP. First of all, one should model the data structure to work with. Therefore, the problem could be solved clearly.

Here is my working code (it requires PHP >= 5.3):

```
<?php

$h2 = Element::fromString('H2');
//var_dump($h2->getName()); // H
//var_dump($h2->getNumber()); // 2

$o2 = Element::fromString('O2');
//var_dump($o2->getName()); // O
//var_dump($o2->getNumber()); // 2

$h2o = ElementGroup::fromString('H2O');
foreach ($h2o->getElements() as $element) {
    var_dump($element->getName());
    var_dump($element->getNumber());
}
// this should print :
// H
// 2
// O
// 1

/* element for H2 or O2 */
class Element
{
    /* example : H */
    private $name;

    /* example : 2 */
    private $number;

    public function __construct($name, $number = 0)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->number = $number;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getNumber()
    {
        return $this->number;
    }

    public static function fromString($string)
    {
        preg_match('/([a-zA-Z])(\d*)/', $string, $matches);

        $element = new self($matches[1], ($matches[2] != '') ? (int)$matches[2] : 1);
        return $element;
    }
}

/* H2O */
class ElementGroup
{
    private $elements = array();

    public function addElement(Element $element)
    {
        $this->elements[] = $element;
    }

    public function getElements()
    {
        return $this->elements;
    }

    public static function fromString($string)
    {
        preg_match_all('/[a-zA-Z]\d*/', $string, $matches);

        $elementGroup = new self();
        if (!empty($matches)) {
            foreach ($matches[0] as $elementString) {
                $elementGroup->addElement(Element::fromString($elementString));
            }
        }

        return $elementGroup;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function make(array $arr, $fullName) {
    $struct = array(
        $fullName => array()
    );

    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        $atomAmount = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $item);
        $atomName = str_replace($atomAmount, '', $item);

        $struct[$fullName][$atomName] = (int) $atomAmount;
    }

    return $struct;
}

make(array('H2', 'O2'), 'H2O');
```

This function returns:

```
array (size=1)
  'H2O' => 
    array (size=2)
      'H' => int 2
      'O' => int 2
```

I think this structure of an array is better.